# Python how to ensure file writing completely when closing program?

Tags: python, destructor

I have a python script which dump yaml file every second while running. However, I found sometimes the yaml file is not completed. My guess is it is coincidence that at the same time I am closing the progress (the script is running in Windows commend line), while the file is saving. Sample code as following:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.__t = threading.Thread(name='StateAutoSave', target=self.__auto_save)
        self.__t.start()

    def __auto_save(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                ...
                self.__save()
            except Exception as err:
                logging.exception(err)
            time.sleep(1)

    def __save(self):
        ...
        with open(self.__yaml_file, 'w') as outfile:
            yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

How to avoid this problem? or is there a method like destructor function in python, so that we can do something when the program is being closed? (It seems that 'with' does not fully work here)

Comment: Suggestion: add an except clause which is only catching `KeyboardInterrupt`(i assume you stop the script via ctrl+c?) and let your save function do its thing then or use the `finally` clause since it was designed for pretty much this purpose ;>

Comment: @meissner_ Nice idea, I will try. Actually I am exiting with just close the commend line window...

Comment: @meissner_ I found keyboardInterrupt seems being ignored under multi-threading situation. There are some Q and A about this and I am working on this.

Answer (score 0):

The atexit module is made just for this purpose.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html

Just beware that it only works for normal termination of the script (ctrl + c is considered normal), and it won't work if you app suddenly crashes or you have to force close it.

Comment: "The functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called." Does it mean closing cmd window will trigger the registered funcs?

Comment: Yes, closing a terminal is handled by python, so it will trigger. I believe all the regular POSIX terminal signals are handled